# Can I use the C++ connector to SQLite or MySQL without knowing SQL?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I'm a beginner and I fairly know C++ and nothing really about databases (except that they're an organized collection of data and you access them with SQL). I wanted to know if i can use the c/c++ connector to a database  without actually knowing SQL

I'm trying to start a project in C++ and while researching ways apps store data, I came across SQLite. I was wondering if i could avoid using SQL. And if I can, is it a bad idea?

Comment: Most likely you can’t and it’s a bad idea to even try. Basic operations aren’t hard to learn so just grab a tutorial and go from there.

Comment: The SQL was invented to make working with relational databases as simple as it can get. Are you asking if there are some other ways? Sure there are but these are way more beginner-hostile.

Comment: It depends on your data. If you have just 1 flat table, then you do not necessariliy need an relational database or SQL. If you have relational data or big data then you need both

Comment: How else could I store program data. For instance if I wanted to keep a record of my courses in college, would a database be the best option or a normal c++ file I/O which is difficult for me to read, write, and especially edit data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer with "it depends" but that is the truth. The answer to your question depends on what data your application is planning to store. So presuming for a moment that you want to store data for which a relational database is the rational choice then …

1. Can you avoid SQL? Yes some databases, including SQLite to some degree, have API calls that you can use to carry out certain actions against the database. In addition many frameworks have support for various databases that provide API level access (possibly even including query builders etc.) that free you from writing SQL directly.
2. If you can is it a bad idea? My opinion is that yes, it is a bad idea to avoid using SQL when working with a SQL database. SQL is somewhat standard so if you ever plan to switch from one DB to another it is far easier to change the SQL than it would be to reimplement a new set of C/C++ API calls against the new DB. The implementation of the SQL language does differ between DBs but in my opinion that difference is easier to deal with than recoding API calls. You asked about SQLite, which is a local-only DB, but if your app grew to needing a client-server DB you will be really happy you had invested in writing SQL instead of pure C/C++ API calls.